# Vuetify radio group component - bind value to v-model in parent

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have the following. A parent view with two fields that go in the parent form. The `v-text-field` is working as intended with it binding to the model in the parent. The radio field as shown in the code snippet doesn't. I have found a workaround which involves giving the radio a v-model itself and emitting a `v-on:change` event and handling that with a method in the parent view.
I wonder if there is a more elegant way of doing this similar to what is being done with the textfield .

Form.vue

```
<Text v-model="textVal"></Text>
<Radio v-model="radioVal"></Radio>

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      textVal: '',
      radioVal: '',
    }
  }
}
```

Text.vue

```
<v-text-field
  :value="value"
  v-on:input="$emit('input', $event)"
></v-text-field>
```

Radio.vue

```
<v-radio-group
  :value="value"
  v-on:input="$emit('input', $event)"
>
  <v-radio value="one" label="One"></v-radio>
  <v-radio value="two" label="Two"></v-radio>
</v-radio-group>
```

Comment: have you looked at the docs? https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-radio-group/#api-events - there is no "input" event - you probably want `v-on:change`

Comment: I have a v-model prop on the <Radio> component in the parent and changed the radio event to: `v-on:change="$emit('change', $event)"` but the v-model stays empty.
Edit: it should be `v-on:change="$emit('input', $event)"`. It works now, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The radio should emit an input event on change like so:

```
<v-radio-group
  :value="value"
  v-on:change="$emit('input', $event)"
>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also just use a v-model on the v-radio-group element. For example:

```
<v-radio-group
  v-model='holderVariable'
>
  <v-radio value="one" label="One"></v-radio>
  <v-radio value="two" label="Two"></v-radio>
</v-radio-group>
```

the holder variable would then have the value of whichever radio button is clicked